# Use exploded array as a list within a while loop

Tags: php, arrays

I got a while loop that shows some old data. I recently added a new tablerow to the database that contains a string thats exploded into an array at every comma.

I then use a for loop to show the array values into a list and use the variable that contains the list in the echoed while loop data.

My code (only relevant parts):

```
while($row_items = mysqli_fetch_array($res_items, MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {

    if($row_items['checkpoints'] != ''){
        $check = explode(',', $row_items['checkpoints']);
    }else{
        $check = '';    
    }

    foreach($check as $list){
        $checklist .= '<li>'.$list.'</li>'; 
    }

      echo '
      <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portf">
        <a class="fancybox" href="../../catalogus/'.$row_items['afbeelding'].'">
          <div class="gallery-item">
              <div class="image">
                  <img src="../../catalogus_icons/'.$row_items['afbeelding'].'.jpg" alt="" style="border:1px solid #ccc;" class="img-responsive" />
              </div>

              <div class="bottom-info">
                  <div class="name">'.$row_items['naam'].'</div>
                  <div>'.$checklist.'</div>
                  <button class="contact_button buttoncontact btn-primary" style="border-radius:2px;">
                      Contact
                      <span class="icon-mail-alt"></span>
                  </button>
              </div>
          </div>
          </a>
      </div>';
    }
```

But this shows the same list on every div output (while loop result). I added 1 list to test, and it adds that list to every item, not only the item that has a list. How can I make sure it only adds the list to the correct result?

`$row_items['checkpoints'];` contains: 'goedkoop,snel,test'

Comment: What is the result of this `$row_items['checkpoints']`?

Comment: try to put $checklist = ''; before for each loop of $check

Comment: @aldrin27 added it in the question

Comment: Reset your `$checklist` if no data in `$check `, cause if the `$check'` is empty the foreach loop don't get executed and the old data stores in `$checklist` as it is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely because you are not clearing the `$checklist` variable between iterations of the loop. You are simply adding to the same list every iteration.

```
while ($row_items = mysqli_fetch_assoc($res_items)) {

    $checklist = '';
    if ($row_items['checkpoints'] != '') {
        $check = explode(',', $row_items['checkpoints']);
        foreach($check as $list) {
            $checklist .= '<li>'.$list.'</li>'; 
        }
    }

    echo '
    <div class="col-lg-2 col-md-3 col-sm-6 col-xs-6 portf">
      <a class="fancybox" href="../../catalogus/'.$row_items['afbeelding'].'">
        <div class="gallery-item">
            <div class="image">
                <img src="../../catalogus_icons/'.$row_items['afbeelding'].'.jpg" alt="" style="border:1px solid #ccc;" class="img-responsive" />
            </div>

            <div class="bottom-info">
                <div class="name">'.$row_items['naam'].'</div>
                <div>'.$checklist.'</div>
                <button class="contact_button buttoncontact btn-primary" style="border-radius:2px;">
                    Contact
                    <span class="icon-mail-alt"></span>
                </button>
            </div>
        </div>
        </a>
    </div>';
}
```